# rails, adding an undefined attribute to form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

i was wondering how do you put a "data-provide" attribute inside a rails form_tag? the html output i would like is...

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
```

however in a form_tag, i can't just do something like

```
<%= f.text_field :data-provide => "typehead" %>
```

how can i add an undefined attribute like that in a form tag? do i need to submit a hidden field or use another helper method? i was looking through the form_tag helper api and it doesn't seem like i can just define another attribute.

it seems like there an easy solution to this, but im not quite sure. help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `:data` option with a hash:

```
<%= f.text_field :some_field, :data => {:provide => "typeahead"} %>
```

Comment: hmmm i still cant them get to work, but i shall try some more. thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that you were using in your question both `typehead` and `typeahead` values. `:data => {:provide => "typeahead"}` definitely works -- I tested it and plus there isn't that much for glitching :) But your misprint could cause some undesirable consequences. Goog luck with your app!