# How to define a data attribute in a Rails form field to render correctly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to implement [Bootstrap Markdown](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/) in my Rails app, which creates a UI for tagging text with markdown.

Now in pure HTML, the markdown buttons can be called through a data attribute like so:

```
    <form>
    <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title?" />
    <textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" data-iconlibrary="fa" rows="10"></textarea>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input name="publish" type="checkbox"> Publish
    </label>
    <hr/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Everything works fine (after installing css and js files for the Bootstrap Markdown). I need to adapt this into a Rails form field though for my project. Using this answer, [I used a data hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294430/rails-adding-an-undefined-attribute-to-form-tag), and I did it like so:

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => "30", :rows => "15", :data => {:provide => "markdown", :iconlibrary => "fa"}, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The weird part is that it is rendering -- but only after I refresh the form when I run it locally.

I also restarted the server to refresh the resources. Same behavior. Renders perfectly after refreshing the page.

Any ideas why that could be? I am wondering if I got the hash idea wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by after refreshing the page? Are you loading form through ajax/turbolinks?

Comment: Pretty sure you are using turbolinks. Disable it and watch the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the data attributes like this:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :cols => "30", :rows => "15", 'data-provide': "markdown", 'data-iconlibrary': "fa", class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: haven't worked for me (Rails 7.1): `<%= render partial: 'income_dashboard', 'data-assets-manager-target': 'dashboard' %>`. The name of my controller is `assets-manager`.